# Python how to start 2 timers in the program

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a program with a bot, which during the working time should also save a list of orders every 10 minutes, as well as save logs every 1 minute. Part of the code is as follows:

```
timer1 = threading.Timer(600, save_orders_list)
timer2 = threading.Timer(60, save_log)
bot.infinity_polling(timeout = 10, long_polling_timeout = 5)

timer1.start()
timer1.join()
timer2.start()
timer2.join()
time.sleep(57600)
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4092053/python-timers-not-working) it was advised to add join() to each timer, but still the save functions are performed correctly separately from the timers.

What can be done in this case?

Comment: What do you what if your save functions are running normally? Do you want some bugs? then allow me to add some . .

Comment: I need the functions to be called periodically. But now they do not work periodically; if they are called manually, they are executed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options to achieve what you are willing to, the very basic example is by using recursion & sleep function e.g.

```
import sched, time

def save_log():
    #your code to save logs
    time.sleep(60) # 1 min
    save_log() #after waiting for 1 min call the function again to save logs
```

Or you can use infinite loop with time function

```
while True:
    save_log()
    time.sleep(60) #wait for 1 min before next iteration
```

The above two approaches are not the neat way to achieve goal, other option which is neat as well as yet more advance way to handle this use case is following

```
s = sched.scheduler(time.time, time.sleep) #define a scheduler
def save_log(sc):
    #your code to save log
    sc.enter(60, 1, save_log, (sc,)) #schedule the next execution 1 min

s.enter(60, 1, save_log, (s,)) #Set first time schedule, 1 min
s.run()
```

You can check some more schedulers to meet your requirements from python official documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sched.html#sched.scheduler)

Comment: Thanks for answer. It worked. As it turned out, the code for calling the bot must also be added to the scheduler for parallel operation of all functions